# How to run 2 different commands on deploy and restart using Node.js on Heroku?

Tags: node.js, heroku, deployment

I am writing a Node.js app and using Heroku to host it. And also I use Webpack + Babel to bundle all my server files into one and to use ES2015 syntax. But the thing is, I need to build my app before running it. So I put this command into `package.json`:

```
"scripts": {
  "start": "webpack && node build/server.js"
},
```

This works, but the problem is, when I run `heroku restart`, my app runs only after rebuild. And the same story when my app crashes.

So I guess I need 2 different commands: one on deploy (`webpack`) and one in `npm start` (`node build/server.js`)

How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually it was not that hard. Just had to change my `package.json` to

```
"scripts": {
  "heroku-postbuild": "webpack",
  "start": "node build/server.js"
}
```

(according to this article: [Heroku Node.js Support](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/nodejs-support#customizing-the-build-process))